# Google ArCore Sceenform - ModelRenderable with glTF or GLB at runtime load causes app crash

Tags: android, runtime, arcore, gltf, sceneform

I am facing a strange issue trying to view a ModelRenderable with SceneForm by downloading a glTF or a glb model at runtime. The application crashes unexpectedly without prompting any valuable error log in the logcat, only a sigsev error. If i try to view this models with ArCore's NativeSceneViewer it is displayed correctly.
The only thing that i see that my models differs from other models that i found on the internet is that both have a "data:application/octet-stream;base64" defined in the uri param from the buffer section like this:

```
"buffers":[{"byteLength":31858968,"uri":"data:application/octet-stream;base64,mQMAAJcDAACKAwAAmAMA..."}]
```

With other models with a valid uri or binary payload everything works correctly.

My question is: why does everything works with google's NativeSceneViewer with the to mentioned models but my app crashes unexpectedly?

I tried both 1.15 and the latest version of Sceneform with 1.21 version of arcore

Comment: I don't know why it's crashing, but there are tools available to convert between the various forms of glTF, if that's helpful in avoiding this crash.

Comment: Hi emacket! My problem is that I am not the owner of those models and cannot convert them, I can only use and show them in my application. Its been days since I am debugging this issue, and I am wondering why the NativeSceneViewer can display them correctly.